# Reading DWORD from binary file

Tags: c, input

Why these lines of code doesn't work when i try to read a `DWORD num = 1880762702` using `fread(&num, "file path", 1, FILE*);`  I get the `result = 10574` if I change the num to any other number say `2880762702` only then it works.

Comment: The code you provided wouldn't even compile. Please provide a complete snippet of code...

Comment: can you clarify your question a bit please. post the actual code of your program, including the declaration of the variables used in your code, and calls to fopen() and fclose().

Answer (score 4):

To read a multibyte quantity such as a DWORD (which is Win32-speak for a 32-bit number) you need to be aware of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It's best to read the number one byte at a time, and convert from the byte ordering used in the file.

```
FILE *in;
DWORD num = 0;

if((fin = fopen("filename.bin", "rb")) != NULL)
{
  unsigned char b0, b1, b2, b3;

  fread(&b3, sizeof b3, 1, in);
  fread(&b2, sizeof b2, 1, in);
  fread(&b1, sizeof b1, 1, in);
  fread(&b0, sizeof b0, 1, in);

  // Assuming file is big-endian.
  // for little endian, swap the order to b0...b3
  num = (((DWORD) b3) << 24) | (((DWORD) b2) << 16) | (((DWORD) b1) << 8) | b0;

  fclose(in);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `fread()` is the size of the data you want to read. In your case, that's `sizeof(DWORD)`.